# What do I have to do to call this events to be display on the web page?

Tags: solidity, dapps, dapp-development, react

How do I call `showLottery` to display on my webpage?

#### Front-End

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    address: '',
    lottery: '',
    events: '',
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    await window.ethereum.enable()
    this.w3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    const address = (await this.w3.eth.getAccounts())[0]
    this.setState({ address })

    this.contract = new this.w3.eth.Contract([
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "implement",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "_lottery",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "showLottery",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "num",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      }
    ], "0xF666108e057d5CA30a962eEf43Ef25ff52b70364")

    const lottery = await this.contract.methods.num().call()
    this.setState({lottery})


  }

  async randLottery() {
    await this.contract.methods.implement().send({from : (await this.w3.eth.getAccounts())[0]});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Address KUU: {this.state.address}</p>
        <button onClick={this.randLottery.bind(this)}>Rand</button>
        <p>Lottery Number: {this.state.lottery}</p>
        <p>History Number: {this.state.events}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Smart Contract

```
contract testRand {

    uint256 public num;

    event showLottery(uint256 _lottery);

    function rand() private view returns (uint256) {
       return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, now , block.coinbase)))%(10**6);
    }

    function implement() public {
        num = rand();
        emit showLottery(num);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post this in plain-text, so that we can use it in order to refer to your question (when posting comments or answers to it).

Comment: @goodvibration I have edited the content from the image to code.

Comment: Add `return` at the beginning of function `randLottery`, and do some debugging to see what it returns when you call it. Being that this function is `async`, you'll have to call it with `await` of course. When you do so, you'll notice that your event is embedded in the response object. See exactly where it is stored within that object, and add in to your webpage code (which you haven't bothered to post here).

Comment: @goodvibration I'm sorry I don't understand because I am a beginner.

Comment: I didn't write anything which a beginner could not understand, and I'm really not sure how I can write it in simpler words.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm sorry
The randLottery () works normally. It can retrun the value. I didn't add code return.
And that I want my front-end to be able to display the information of the event pulled from showLottery () in smartcontract.